# On using Publish().RefCount()

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I find myself often wanting to use `Publish().RefCount()` to 'protect my sources'.

For example, when translating some incoming IObservable json into two IObservable properties:

```
var anon = source.Select(TranslateToAnonObject);
this.Xs = anon.Select(GetXFromAnonObject);
this.Ys = anon.Select(GetYFromAnonObject);
```

To avoid performing the translation twice, I'd be tempted to put a `Publish().RefCount()` behind the anon definition.

And same thing for both property values, to avoid performing the `Get..` functions separately for each subscriber.

The thing is, it's getting to the point where I can't really see many situations where I *wouldn't* want this. But if that was right, it would surely be the default in Rx. What am I thinking wrong?

*(Thinks: is it because I'm almost exclusively working with 'hot' observables?)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do quite often want to do this. In fact I wrote an [article](http://www.zerobugbuild.com/?p=144) on this very point. The reason why it isn't the default is simply that it isn't required all the time (and is easier to omit than switch off); there are many cases where it just adds overhead and there are more than a few cases where Publish() with connection control is needed because the subscriber count can fall to zero and re-subscribing would have unintended side effects, particularly (as you said) when dealing with cold observables.

Comment: Yes, overhead is something I was wondering about, but I guess it's a trade-off, and depends on throughput, and how many subscribers one expects.

Comment: The big issue with this is if the observable produces values after the first observer subscribes but subsequent subscribers do - in that case the subsequent subscribers miss out on on the earlier values. I think a lot of people don't expect this. If you need each subscriber to get all values then just do `.Publish()` without the `.RefCount()`.